# Can imagedefinitions.json refer to an existing task definition?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

My current setup uses AWS CodeBuild to build a docker-image and pushes it to AWS ECR.
The imagedefinitions.json file is required for the deploy step in CodePipeline to deploy a docker image from ECR to a ECS service.
From my understanding this file is used to define a new task definition. I currently define this file in the buildspec.yml file in CodeBuild:

```
echo Writing image definitions file...  
- printf '[{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"}]' $MODULE $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json    

artifacts:  
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

However, I would like to use an existing task definition instead of creating a new revision of the same task definition for each build. I need to use the environmental variables defined in my existing task definition, and I have not found a way to define these in the imagedefinitions.json file either.

1. Can imagedefinitions.json be used to specify an existing task definition?
2. Or, can I specify environmental variables in this file?

Answer (score 1):

> Can imagedefinitions.json be used to specify an existing task definition?

The “imagedefinitions.json” file does not define an ECS task. It defines a container_name (part of an ECS Task Definition) and image_name:tag.

```
[
  {
    "name": "sample-app",
    "imageUri": "11111EXAMPLE.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ecs-repo:latest"
  }
]
```

In an ECS Deploy action, you specify the cluster name and service name. Add the two items from “imagedefinitions.json” i.e. container_name and image:tag and ECS job worker has all the information it needs to create a Task Definition revision and update a Service (a service has an associated task definition).

**ECS Deploy Action definition in a Pipeline:**

```
      {
            "name": "Deploy",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "Deploy",
                    "actionTypeId": {
                        "category": "Deploy",
                        "owner": "AWS",
                        "provider": "ECS",
                        "version": "1"
                    },
                    "runOrder": 1,
                    "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::<Account>:role/Pipeline_Role",
                    "configuration": {
                        "ClusterName": "<Cluster>",     <====================
                        "ServiceName": "<Service>”      <====================
                    },
                    "outputArtifacts": [],
                    "inputArtifacts": [
                        {
                            "name": "SourceArtifact"
                        }
                    ],
                    "region": "us-east-1"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Note that the result of Deploy stage using ECS Deploy action is a new Task definition revision that will include the updated Image URI for the specified container in the task definition. Your other task definition parameters (e.g. environment variables) should remain unchanged.

> Or, can I specify environmental variables in this file?

No, but as discussed above, your existing Task Def (the TaskDef from which a new revision is created) environment variables will remain as it is.

Let me know if there is any confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I did also assume that this was the case. However, the environmental variables are also defined inside the container definition and they seem to be "forgotten" once a new revision is made?

Comment: Are your env variables defined in Task Def? Can you share the task definition?

Comment: {
  "containerDefinitions": [{
    "secrets": [{
      "name": "environment_variable_name",
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:region:aws_account_id:parameter/parameter_name"
    }]
  }]
}

Comment: I've met exactly same confition right now, and I've avoid issue by "unregister all taskdefinitions which not contains environment variables.".